# How to append long html files WITH SPACE?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If this html code is as long as 300 lines. You have to write codes without space. But any Code Editor gives space between of tags. And I have to delete all space. Is there any solution for it?

```
$("body").append($("<div id='dzndiv'><div style='position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;width:100%;height:800px;'>
                <img src='img/transparent.png' width='100%' height='100%'/></div></div>"));
```

It is not true but solution example like this or equal?:

```
$("body").append($.load("longstuff.html"));
```

Comment: There is no `$.load` method (if you meant `$.fn.load`, it works differently)

Comment: Why do you need your HTML without any whitespace?

Comment: Are you talking about that line feeds (not just space) are not allowed inside JavaScript string literals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually pretty close ;)
Try

```
$("body").load("longstuff.html");
```

or better create a div somewhere and do

```
$("#yourDivId").load("longstuff.html");
```

or have a look at

http://api.jquery.com/load/